# Passion in CouchBase Programming

Tags: couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I would like to get the single element in the Couchbase document that is in the array of objects, but i am able to fetch the array of objects

i tried to fetch the array using the following query, `'select countryDetails from test';`

```
{
   "type":"countries",
   "docName":"CountryData",
   "countryDetails":[
      {
         "name":"US",
         "code":"+1",
         "stateInfo":[
            {
               "name":"Florida",
               "id":"1212"
            },
            {
               "name":"NewYork",
               "id":"1214"
            }
         ]
      },
       {
         "name":"France",
         "code":"+33",
         "stateInfo":[
            {
               "name":"Grand Est",
               "id":"5212"
            },
            {
               "name":"Brittany",
               "id":"5214"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

i tried fetching array using, `select countryDetails from test;`

i like to fetch the result as `[ {"name" : "US", "code" : "+1" }, {"name" : "France", "code" : "+33"}]`

Comment: why i was given downvote, anything needs to be corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you project countryDetails it projects whole sub object.
If you need to part of sub object you need to explicitly project that.

The following ARRAY construction will provide the data representation you are expecting.

```
SELECT ARRAY {v.name,v.code} FOR v IN t.countryDetails END AS contryDetails
FROM test AS t 
WHERE t.type = "countries";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do does not seem to be possible. You can get closer to what you want with a query like this:

```
select raw countryDetails from test
```

But the results of this query still have the result wrapped in an extra level of array.